# Why not use only two way data binding?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

Why shouldn't I use two way data binding all the time?

Comment: There are many situations, when software just reads the data ,i.e displaying data on a table etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're first starting angular, it's ok to use 2 way binding. But it got some disadvantages.

First things comes to my mind are:
It's template driven what that means is: you can't dynamically add or remove data to bind. You have'll to define all data fields at HTML and then hide or show them.

Second is angular has change dedection cycle running behind the veils. It constantly checks if anything changed so it can update its counterpart. When you application is growing bigger and bigger, this performance load is adds up. And then you have to optimize.

As I say, as a newcomer, you can use it. But you'll experience why you should use one way bindings and the other ways of angular yourself.

Comment: Thanks i have one extra question
should I use FormGroup for geting data form a view to submit ?

Comment: This may help.. A three part series on 2way binding https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m

Comment: Actually I'll give same answer as above. FormGroup is dynamic, and ngModel is template driven. You can't change the forms and other data dynamicly with ngModel. You should learn how to use both of them.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: Angular's change detection goes perfectly hand in hand with immutability of objects, but two-way data binding mutates objects.